# How to distribute App with quicklook plugin

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, app-store, quicklook

I have finished myApp with a Quick Look plugIn. Then I add a bulid phase in xcode to copy the plugIn to myApp.app/Library/QuickLook/ .Now I want to distribute it to app store and I found that the archive file xxx.xcarchive have two product in: plugin and myApp. And I can't distribute to App Store.....

Anyone come across a problem like this? Should I copy the plugin manually? Or AppStore don't accept app with QuickLook plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your build settings `Skip Install` to `Yes` for your `Release` build for the quicklook plugin target.

[image]